# jquery - setting dynamic equal height of a floated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, css-float

I have 2 div containers, one navigation on the left, one content right to that:

```
#leftnav_static
{
padding:5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
height: 1000px;
width: 195px;
font-size: 1.35em;
float:left;
background-image: url('pagenav.jpg');
}

#content_dynamic
{
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 215px;
height: auto;
width: 700px;
padding: 5px;
background-image: url('pagenav.jpg');
font-size: 1em;
line-height:1.6em;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Now I want to set leftnav to the same height as content (no faux columns if possible):

```
$('#leftnav_static').height($("#content_dynamic").height());
```

or

```
$('#leftnav_static').innerHeight($("#content_dynamic").innerHeight());
```

dont seem to work.

any suggestions as to why that is?

Answer (score 2):

It does work.  See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwolfetech/FVeVv/).

Are you running the code in a jQuery ready block?  Also, if you want to maintain this height relationship through text size changes from browser 'zooms', you will need to respond to resize events.  If at some point you make your `content_dynamic` div have a width of auto, you will also need to resize the sidebar div when the height of the `content_dynamic` div changes (again, by responding to a resize event).

jQuery only allows you to attach to a resize event at the window level, but there are plugins that ease translating that to a div level resize event.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="leftnav_static"></div>
 <div id="content_dynamic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam iaculis ornare 
   sapien sit amet condimentum. Aliquam a diam vel eros
   tristique fermentum vitae at turpis. Etiam fringilla,
   enim nec viverra interdum, metus tortor vehicula mauris,
   in luctus felis massa ut nulla. Proin et leo vel nunc ornare
   pulvinar. Vestibulum quis lectus  vel arcu tristique aliquet.
   Fusce malesuada nisi non ante egestas semper. 
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#leftnav_static {
    padding:5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 195px;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
}

#content_dynamic {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 215px;
    height: auto;
    width: 700px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height:1.6em;
    //white-space:nowrap;  //This makes the content div only one line, 
                           //I commented this out to make the sizing clear.
 }
```

**JavaScript**: (Assuming that the jQuery library is already loaded)

```
$(function() {
    $('#leftnav_static').height($("#content_dynamic").height());
});
```

**Note:** The benefit of a faux columns or other pure CSS approaches is that you don't need to worry about zooming or resizes as much--and your site would work for people that have JavaScript turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that you are manipulating CSS attributes.

```
var myHeight = $("#content_dynamic").css("height");
$('#leftnav_static').css({"height": myHeight});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: You can set heights without setting the CSS attribute.  There might be valid reasons to set it as a CSS attribute, but I don't *think* it is necessary in this case.  Was there a particular reason to do it this way?

Comment: First, it works, and it seems natural to manipulate this with CSS if the height has been set in CSS ... other than that: when you set no html attribute `height`, I do believe (and have not tested it) that there is no .height() value set. When something is not set, you cannot write it into another .height() (this is mere speculation).

Comment: I don't think it matters if a height is set in the CSS explicitly--height() still knows the calculated height--that is, at least when the DOM is ready.  It may be different if you mean before the DOM is ready and if you just included the JavaScript in the head section of the html.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/mwolfetech/FVeVv/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add display block to #leftnav_static

```
#leftnav_static
{
  display: block;
}
```

...and this will work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#leftnav_static').height( $('#content_dynamic').height() );
});
```

See my example; http://jsfiddle.net/D3gTy/